# How to record quick GIF screencasts with keyboard shortcuts in Windows?

Tags: gif

Similar to https://superuser.com/questions/81826/how-do-i-create-a-gif-screencast-in-windows but I'm looking for a tool / workflow that can incorporate **keyboard shortcuts** I have pressed into the final GIF. For example, I wasn't able to do this easily with ScreenToGif which, other than that, seems really nice.

Comment: Should the other question be moved there then? http://superuser.com/questions/81826/how-do-i-create-a-gif-screencast-in-windows

Comment: Maybe. The difference is 1/ It's an old question and standards have changed 2/ The other question is not asking for a tool 3/ This question is asking for a tool.

Comment: Updated the question to make it clear that it can also be a workflow. However, if you can migrate it to softwarerect, I agree that it might a better place for this question.

Comment: You can flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it.